# IIS -> PHP -> Wordpress - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I'm trying to install Wordpress on IIS, but this annoying problem has been getting on my nerves.

The WP is installed on a Windows Server 2012 with IIS installed (other ASP.NET sites work on it).

There is no firewall enabled on Windows Server.

The login screen disappears if I set the user in IIS, but still giving problem ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED to anyone who tries to access the blog externally to the server.

I have also tried:

- Give folder access permission the user anonimous, but had no effect.
- Activate SSL, which had no effect either.
- Disable SSL on wordpress: define(‘FORCE_SSL_ADMIN’, false); define(‘FORCE_SSL_LOGIN’, false); on WP_Config.php
- Disable php_openssl.dll on PHP Extensions

Follows a print (left the screen of an external user and right navigation screen from the server):
[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://blog.pluralsight.com/installing-wordpress-on-iis7

I removed the mysql and installed the current version.

I changed the permissions to full control of phpsessions folder for users: IUSR; IIS_IUSRS; Network Service